# Copy N days old files on Linux

Tags: linux, copy, cp, datemodified

Good morning,

I have many files inside directories, subdirectories which I'm now using copy everything inside.

```
find /tmp/temp/ -name *files.csv -type f -exec cp -u {}  /home/dir/Desktop/dir1/ \;
```

And I was wondering, if there is anyway that I can copy like, copy if the file's modified date is within two days. I don't want to copy if the modification date is 2 days before the current date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mtime` within your find command:

```
find /tmp/temp/ -type f -mtime -2 -name *files.csv -exec cp -u {}  /home/dir/Desktop/dir1/ \;
```

This would copy only files with a modified time within the last two days of the system time.

```
-mtime n
    File's data was last modified n*24 hours ago
```